# Is it a "14-karat gold ring" or a "14-karat-gold ring"?

Tags: hyphenation

I cannot find an answer to this anywhere, neither on the internet nor in any jeweler brochures.

Is it:

> a 14-karat-gold ring

OR:

> a 14-karat gold ring

Does "14-karat" modify "gold ring"—or does "14-karat-gold" modify "ring"?

---

Lastly, is it:

> a 14-karat gold-plated necklace?

OR:

> a 14-karat-gold-plated necklace?

Comment: I included what research I did.